# Trying to get property of non-object in select

Tags: codeigniter

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: models/Tournaments_model.php

Line Number: 101

I have this problem. In my project a need, that when I select a selection, I can select several options

my model

```
function create_new_tournaments($id, $name, $about, $date, $reg_date, $time, $city, $address, $country, $photo, $type)
{
    $maxid = 0;
    //$this->load->database();
    $row = $this->ci->db->query("SELECT MAX(id) AS maxid FROM tournaments")->row();
    if ($row) {
        $maxid = $row->maxid;
    }
    $maxid++;

    // Define data to insert

    $data = array(
        "id"=>$maxid,
        "name" => $name,
        "description" => $about,
        "date" => $date,
        "registration_date" => $reg_date,
        "time" => $time,
        "city" => $city,
        "address" => $address,
        "country" => $country,
        "poster" => $photo,
        "type" => $type,

    );


    // If inserting data fails
    if (!$this->ci->db->insert("tournaments", $data)) {
        // Return false
        return FALSE;
    }

    foreach ($id as $id_categories) {

        $data2 = array(
            "tournament_id" => $maxid,
            "category_id" => $id_categories->id,

        );

        if (!$this->ci->db->insert("tournament_categories", $data2)) {
            // Return false
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

my controller:

```
$id = $this->input->post('select_categories');
```

my view:

```
<select class="js-example-basic-multiple form-control" id="select_categories" name="select_categories[]" multiple="multiple">
```

Comment: Line 101 is she: "category_id" => $id_categories->id (in my model: foreach)

Comment: Id object is not present in $id array. Do print_r($id) and check.

Answer (score 1):

It's an array ,  elements in the array can be accessed like this

```
$id_categories['id']
```

Your $data2 would be now

```
$data2 = array(
            "tournament_id" => $maxid,
            "category_id" => $id_categories['id'],

        );
```

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Illegal string offset 'id'

Filename: models/Tournaments_model.php

Line Number: 99

Comment: can you print the value of id before for loop and post it  here ?

Comment: `$data2 = array(
                "tournament_id" => $maxid,
                "category_id" => $id_categories

            );`

Comment: try echo "<pre>";
     print_r($id);

before  for loop